# Calculation of eigenvalues in a Markov Chain

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

Finding the eigenvalues of $A=(p_{ij})$ where $\sum_{i=1}^3 p_{ij}=1$ for all $j=1,2,3.$

In the $2 \times 2 $ case have $\lambda_1=p_{11}+p_{22}-1$ and $\lambda_2=1$. I guess for this case $3 \times 3 $ should get something analogous

I appreciate any help.

Comment: "autovales"? ${}{}$

Comment: "Autovalor" is eigenvalue, in portuguese and spanish. I've edited it to match the question title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write out the 3x3 matrix as a function of the transition probabilities, rearranging using the stochasticity property in each column. (That is, write $p_{i3}=1-p_{i1}-p_{i2}$ for each $i$, leaving the other two as parameters). Get its characteristic polynomial. From the stochasticity property, one of the eigenvalues will be $1$. So if you divide the characteristic polynomial by $\lambda-1$, you will get a quadratic polynomial. You can find the roots of this polynomial with the quadratic formula.

Another way to do this is as follows. Set up the system:

$$\lambda_1 = 1 \\
\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = \text{tr}(A) = p_{11} + p_{22} + p_{33} \\
\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3 = \text{det}(A)$$

Substituting the first equation:

$$\lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = \text{tr}(A) - 1 \\
\lambda_2 \lambda_3 = \text{det}(A)$$

These are two equations in two unknowns, which you should be able to solve and then substitute in what $\text{tr}(A)$ and $\text{det}(A)$ are.